# Sharpening Shechita Knife on Chol HaMoaed

Tags: halacha, torah-study, chol-hamoed, slaughter-shochet-shecht

May one that is learning Hilchos Shechita sharpen the knife that he uses for shechitah on chol hamoed for the purpose of practicing how to sharpen it and make sure it's kosher for shechitah (and not to use to shecht on chol hamoed)?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Rabbi at Mosdos Yodai Binah](https://www.abina.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%99%D7%96-%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%99%D7%98%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9F/) it is forbidden for one to sharpen a knife while learning about Shechita on Chol Hamoed.

A Shochet who is slaughtering may sharpen his knife on Chol Hamoed.

Sources: Chazon Ish Hilchos Shabbos 50:9.

Comment: 540:1 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%9E_%D7%90 ?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't a source for this, if your asking למעשה consult a real authority - but I would go the same way as writing. Just as writing is permitted on חול המועד for learning Toarh, if the purpose is learning and not fixing the knife - I'd assume it's OK.

Comment: As I recall, the heter for writing Torah is based on Davar Haaveid: lest you forget your chiddush (at least according to some), not because of "leaning purposes".

Comment: @DoubleAA I think you're right. So if he's afraid of forgetting if he doesn't practice - it's the same.

Comment: @JNF, he's going to forget how to do it if he doesn't do it for a week? This does not strike me as the same thing as coming up with a unique idea in Torah learning and forgetting it if you don't write it down quickly.

Comment: @SethJ, it might be stretched, but I don't see a real difference. If it's his only opportunity to learn and practice...

Comment: @SethJ, one who knows well how to sharpen the knife likely won't forget if he fails to practice for a week, but perhaps the novice would.  Alternatively, if he plans to take his shechita bechina soon after yom tov acharon, and so he wants to be sure he is in good form and practice on chol hamoed?  (Say there is an expert shochet in town for Sukkos.  Isru chag, this student will take the bechina and if he passes, stay in town as the shochet.  But the baki is leaving on Isru chag later in the day.)

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen, if you're inclined, perhaps you could edit that idea into the body of the question. I don't know if it's part and parcel of the question, but it helps. It helped me, anyway, to understand why this would be a relevant skill to practice.